# Feign - handling underling Exceptions - propagating error status

Tags: java, hystrix, feign

This is similar question to [Netflix Feign - Propagate Status and Exception through Microservices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38786207/netflix-feign-propagate-status-and-exception-through-microservices)

I have microservices architecture with feign and hystrix.
My problem is that when underling service returns error response - say status `404` - my FallbackFactory should propagate it, but it always returns `200`.

Here is my code:

ErrorResponseDecoder:

```
@Component
public class ErrorResponseDecoder implements ErrorDecoder {

private ErrorDecoder delegate = new ErrorDecoder.Default();

@Override
public Exception decode(String methodKey, Response response) {
    HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    for(Map.Entry<String,Collection<String>> entry : response.headers().entrySet()) {
        responseHeaders.put(entry.getKey(), new ArrayList<>(entry.getValue()));
    }
    HttpStatus statusCode = HttpStatus.valueOf(response.status());
    String statusText = response.reason();

    byte[] responseBody;
    try {
        responseBody = IOUtils.toByteArray(response.body().asInputStream());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed to process response body.", e);
    }

    if (response.status() >= 400 && response.status() <= 499) {
        return new HttpClientErrorException(statusCode, statusText, responseHeaders, responseBody, null);
    }

    if (response.status() >= 500 && response.status() <= 599) {
        return new HttpServerErrorException(statusCode, statusText, responseHeaders, responseBody, null);
    }
    return delegate.decode(methodKey, response);
}
}
```

Fallback:

```
@Component
public class ServiceFallbackFactory implements FallbackFactory<ServiceFeign> {

@Override
public ServiceFeign create(final Throwable cause) {

    return new ServiceFeign() {

        @Override
        public Response getList(String date) {
            if(cause instanceof HttpStatusCodeException) {
                HttpStatusCodeException exc = (HttpStatusCodeException)cause;
                return Response.status(exc.getStatusCode().value()).entity(exc.getMessage()).build();
            } else {
                throw new RuntimeException(cause);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
{
  "statusType": "NOT_FOUND",
  "entity": "404 Not Found",
  "entityType": "java.lang.String",
  "metadata": {},
  "status": 404
}
```

Http status: 200 :(
How can I make it also 404?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all - I didn't need fallback mechanism for that.

Most likely `ResponseEntity` would work, but I didn't try that with this solution.

For detailed design see: [Hystrix - how to register ExceptionMapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41547708/hystrix-how-to-register-exceptionmapper)